# I unchecked "dim the display", but it's still diming

Tags: display, screen, brightness, asus

I have problem on my asus k55a running ubuntu 13.10. I have unchecked "Dim screen to save power" in Brightness & Lock, but the screen is still dimming after a while. This is very annoying when I'm watching a movie, and it created a problem when I showed my presentation, when the laptop was connected to projector. I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322744/disable-automatic-screen-dimming), but it didn't help. The problem is from the first time I installed ubuntu. Still, I tried to reinstall, but it didn't help, and all of my data is lost! Anyway, reinstalling fixed anther problem, so it's OK. Please help. One more thing, when I was using ubuntu 12.04(before I installed 13.10, I had problem adjusting brightness settings, but it was fixed with the installation of 13.10. Thank you!

Comment: Try `xset -dpms`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked!

> xset -dpms

Thank you!